# Javascript: Use a variable in a string inside an Object

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping the above title is accurate to what I need to do. I've been Googling my face off and nothing seems to be working.

Here is a snippet of my code...

```
var options = {
campaigns: {
    'hydraulic_repair': {
        phone: '(555) 555-5555',
        myform: '<div class="adwords-switched"><iframe src="http://www.mywebsite.com/contact-form-google-sfp/" allowtransparency="true" width="100%" height="725px" type="text/html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe></div>'
    }
}
};
```

I now need to add some variables into the mix. It works fine when I hard code the variables like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/contact-form-google-sfp/**?keyword=HELLO&adgroup=WORLD**

however the keyword and adgroup are going to be dynamic, and when I try to enter variables into the string, it breaks my code. I'm not sure why the "+" concatenation isn't working, is there a different method to add variables in that I'm missing?

```
var mykeyword = 'HELLO';
var myadgroup = 'WORLD';

var options = {
campaigns: {
    'hydraulic_repair': {
        phone: '(555) 555-5555',
        myform: '<div class="adwords-switched"><iframe src="http://www.mywebsite.com/contact-form-google-sfp/?keyword='+mykeyword+'&adgroup='+myadgroup+'" allowtransparency="true" width="100%" height="725px" type="text/html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe></div>'
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Your example works just fine in the console... what are some example values you are using in your variables or what errors if any are you getting?

Comment: The issue is likely with the values of your variables and not the string concatenation technique.

Comment: If you used placeholder code here or if your variables contain a single quote (which would end the string and cause problems when concatenating) you need to escape the quote `var dont = 'don\'t';`

Comment: I will look into all of the above items mentioned, thank you in advance. This is only a snippet of the full code, so it could be the variables. I just know the entire script stops working when I add in the "+" variables, so I thought I would start there.